# mat snackbar unit test message is null

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material

i have a custom service that uses `matSnackbar` to show the alerts, and a custom `matSnackbar` component to use as template for snackBar.
i wrote a unit test for it and want to test the showing my message in it:

```
fit('should show my alert message',  () => {
    service.openSnackBarFromComponent('lia lia');
    expect(element.querySelector('.message-container span').innerText).toBe('lia lia');
  });
```

i see in browser that it shows my message `"lia lia"` but in the test above content of the `.message-container span` in null. my qusetion is why it shows null and or any another way to test my message?

Comment: Try using `fixture.detectChanges()`. But you should not test that the message is displayed, since it's not your own code : you should simply test that the method `openSnackBarFromComponent` is called. If you don't, and tommorow, you change your UI library, your test won't pass anymore.

Comment: @Maryannah so thank you, ```fixture.detectChanges()``` solved my problem. i'm new in unit test, i will do that, thank you.

Comment: Then let me make an answer to explain further my comment.

Comment: @Maryannah yes of Course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following my comment, `fixture.detectChanges` should resolve your issue.

As for unit testing : as you must have guessed, **unit** testing means testing a unit.

A unit is a piece of code

- that you wrote yourself
- that is defined in a given scope (function, class)
- that has dependencies (injection, parameters ...)

When you test that unit, you have several steps to respect

- Mock the dependencies
- Isolate the unit
- Test the side effects

The purpose of unit testing is to **prevent side effects from modifications**.

For instance, you have a component that simply colors a button in green if the HTTP answer is 200.

The unit test purpose is to ensure that the color becomes green if the answer is 200.

This means that if you don't receive 200, the colour should not change, and if you receive 200, the colour should be green only.

Applied to your case, the purpose of your test would be to ensure that the snacker is called with your custom component.

**It's not your purpose to test the snackar works**. The snackbar is a unit itself, and one you did not code : the unit testing of the snackbar is tested by the Angular Material unit tests, not you.

*In fine*, your test isn't wrong : it's just a duplicate of another test, so it's "useless" in the sense that it has already been tested.

If you continue to test like that, you will spend 3, 4 times the time you would have spent testing, which isn't productive in the end.