# How to inject services in to a custom class in beforeEach Karma/Jasmine test in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

Hi I'm triying to test a custom class instantiation, i have several test in the same spec file, that's why use the `beforeEach` method, also i use `inject` method to get the services required by my class, but when i run the test the var `appointmentCreationVehicle` are undefined
this is my code:

```
describe('AppointmentCreationVehicle', () => {
  let appointmentCreationVehicle: AppointmentCreationVehicle;

  beforeAll(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(
    inject([AppointmentCreationVehicle], (vehicleRestService: VehicleRestService) => {
      appointmentCreationVehicle = new AppointmentCreationVehicle(vehicleRestService);
    })
  );
  it('should create an instance',() => {
      expect(appointmentCreationVehicle).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

then my karma.conf.js look like this:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'], 
        plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-firefox-launcher'),
            require('karma-mocha-reporter'),
            require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
        ],
        client: {
            clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
            jasmine: {
                random: false
            },            
            captureConsole: true,
            mocha: {
                bail: true
            }        
        },
        reporters: ['mocha'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: false,
        browsers: ['HeadlessFirefox'],
        singleRun: true,
        customLaunchers: {
            HeadlessFirefox: {
                base: 'Firefox',
                flags: ['-headless']
            },
            ChromeDebugging: {
                base: 'Chrome',
                flags: ['--remote-debugging-port=9876']
            }
        }
    });
};
```

It is possible than the injection of the services ends after the it execution? If i show, how can i avoid this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't import the providers into your testbed :

```
beforeAll(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [...] // <---------- HERE
  })
  .compileComponents();
});
```

After that, make it simpler : use the testbed ! It contains a weekMap of the dependencies :

```
const myServiceInstance = TestBed.get(MyService);
```

Comment: i have the providers in my AppModule. Is necessary to import with TestBed?

Comment: @ErnestoAlfonso maybe you should read [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing) before testing ...

Comment: I mean, if you don't even understand the concept, there's no point in testing for the sake of testing.

Comment: TestBed.configureTestingModule generate a module for testing, it works like other modules with imports, providers etc, if i import a module to the TestingModule it would work like when i do the same in one of my app modules.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, you're not familiar with the concept of unit testing at all. Take some time, read the documentation, and you will understand your errors.

Comment: I think i start to understand what you say, you are saying that a unit test could not have external element involves, only elements needed by the element your are testing?

Comment: @ErnestoAlfonso wow you're a fast reader ! Indeed, unit tests concern single units. I've actually [just answered a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56355275/mat-snackbar-unit-test-message-is-null/56355781#56355781) about the principles of unit testing, if you want the core concepts.

Comment: @ErnestoAlfonso well the documentation does, but you're welcome !